# R programming equivalent of python spaCy 'spacy.explain()'

Tags: python, r, spacy

i was founding 'AUX'.

in python, i used 'spacy.explain('AUX')'. but, in R, i don't know the method.

[image]

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that a method specific to a Python library for NLP would exist in base R, with no NLP packages loaded. You would have to explore what NLP packages are available for R and whether any of them have a similar method. Or you may be able to use the `reticulate` package to call spacy in Python from R.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the R `reticulate` library to access Python.

Provided everything is installed correctly and `Sys.which('python')` points to the correct Python path for the spacy module:

```
library(reticulate)

sp <- import("spacy")

sp$explain("AUX")
[1] "auxiliary"
```